# Calling a value from the database into text field - custom error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following code in my page_load function which basically returns a value from a database based on the zip code the user enters. The problem is, I am running into a custom error issue. When my other two text fields get auto filled, if I wait 5 mins then submit, I will get an error, however, if I submit within 5 mins, everything works as expected. could you please let me know if the way I calling values from the database is wrong, or how I might fix this error? this is the error:

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is my code, (it is pretty basic, I am new to programming):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (txtzip.Text.Length == 5)
    {
        SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP(1) * FROM zip_code WHERE zip = '" + Convert.ToInt32(txtzip.Text) + "'", conn);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();
        if (DR1.Read())
        {
            txtstate.Text = DR1.GetValue(2).ToString();
            txtcity.Text = DR1.GetValue(1).ToString();
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

This is my config file (please note that I replaced my credentials with ......):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="aConn" connectionString="Data Source=.......;Initial Catalog=aspData;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=......"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=......."/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=........"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Tip: Expect a visit from [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). Parameters could be your new best friends. As for your question, is your session expiring in 5 minutes?

Comment: Yes, my session expired in 5 mins. I am not getting any syntax error.

Comment: what does it have to do with 5 min session Im confused

Comment: There must be missing, relevant code somewhere.

Comment: well let me be clear, it is not exactly 5 mins, it is when I fill in the data, I wait for sometime like lets say 4 mins then hit submit, I get that error page. If I fill in the data and just hit submit, everything works fine!

Comment: @user3345212 _what_ error page? What does it say?

Comment: This is the error page, thank you!
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @user3345212 - that isn't the error page. That is a line in the web.config file that says to not use customErrors. I'm asking for the actual error that you get when this fails.

Comment: It is actually solved, I closed the connection in the page load. But believe me, that is an error page I used to get, my config file does not have that. Just google what I sent you about that custom error page, alot of people running into this issue. Thank you for your time looking into this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, few things are wrong, from what you are saying , it seems the connection  gets closed:

- You should create connection when you need it, release it when you done
- A zip code is not of type int.
- `Convert.ToInt32` will give you unexpected result because the leading
  zero will be removed.
- You also need to learn how to use parameterized queries, it will avoid
- SQL injection and also save you from syntax errors.
- `SELECT *` + `.GetValue()` is the receipe for some bugs, if you ever
  modify the table structure or the query you can break your code, instead of column index use the name, and don't use the wildcard `*` select the specific field.
- And last but not least, make use of `using statement` it is more
  efficient way of disposing your objects.

---

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT TOP(1) city, state  FROM zip_code WHERE zip = @zip", connection))
    {

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("zip", txtzip.Text));

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.HasRows())
        {
            var city = reader["city"].ToString();
            var state = reader["state"].ToString();

            Console.WriteLine("City = {0}, State = {1}",
                city,
                state)      

            txtstate.Text = city
            txtcity.Text = state;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was because I closed my connection! And thank you so much for the example above, I definitely need to use your method! can't thank you enough.